# In JS of LWC, line after forEach statement does not execute

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, loop, array, javascript-debugging

I have below Javascript function in lwc

```
apexJobInfoData;
@track isBatch;
getData({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        // TODO: handle error
    } else if (data) {
        this.jobId = getFieldValue(data, JOB_ID);
        getAllApexJobInfo({ ApexJobId: this.jobId})
        .then(result => {
            this.apexJobInfoData = result.JobInfo.length===0?null:result.JobInfo;
            this.error = undefined;

            if(apexJobInfoData!=null){
                apexJobInfoData.forEach((element) => {
                        if(element.JobType === 'BatchApex'){
                            this.isBatch = true;    
                        }
                  })
            }
            alert('Error Calling Alert Here');  // This line does not execute
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.message = undefined;
            this.error = error;
        });
    }
```

I am not sure what's happening but after there is something wrong with below piece of code. After this nothing gets executed.

```
        if(apexJobInfoData!=null){
            console.log('Enters here');
            apexJobInfoData.forEach((element) => {
                 console.log('Doesn't enter here');
              })
        }
```

What am I missing here.

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the result of `apexJobInfoData` after logging it via `console.log`. Maybe it is not an `Array` but a `String` that looks like `Array`. Also, can you add console logs to know exactly at what line does it stop.

Comment: I have added a console log. It does enter into If loop but there is something wrong with how I am using forEach.

Comment: This probably fix your problem, but you could write `this.isBatch = !!apexJobInfoData.find(element=>element.JobType === 'BatchApex')` instead.

Comment: It can be that `apexJobInfoData` is not an `Array` but a `String` like `'[a,b,c,d]'`

Comment: [
  {
    "Id": "7072900001Sf8CmXXXX",
    "JobType": "Future",
    "Status": "Failed",
    "JobItemsProcessed": 0,
    "TotalJobItems": 0,
    "NumberOfErrors": 0,
    "CompletedDate": "2020-03-11T19:15:32.000Z",
    "MethodName": "XX",
    "ExtendedStatus": "XXXX"
  }
]

Comment: This is how it looks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you are missing "this" references:

```
    .then(result => {
        this.apexJobInfoData = result.JobInfo.length===0?null:result.JobInfo;
        this.error = undefined;

        if(this.apexJobInfoData!=null){ // HERE
            this.apexJobInfoData.forEach((element) => { // HERE TOO
                    if(element.JobType === 'BatchApex'){
                        this.isBatch = true;    
                    }
              })
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to catch these kind of mistakes in JS?

Comment: You might find that jslint, eslint or other code checker can help.